# How to pass the credentials window with wds and an xml file on startup?

Tags: windows-10, boot, automation, xml, wds

Good morning,

I installed a windows server 2019 with the Windows Deployment Service (WDS) in standalone mode and I am trying to skip the configuration steps with an xml reply file, which is supposed to answer the questions during the installation. However after the appearance of the Windows logo a window appears asking me for the language and credentials as if the file was not working.

Here is my file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>fr-FR</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>fr-FR</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>fr-FR</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>fr-FR</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>fr-FR</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Size>500</Size>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>Boot</Label>
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <Active>true</Active>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T</Key>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <Organization>hello</Organization>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>fr-FR</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>fr-FR</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>fr-FR</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>fr-FR</UserLocale>
            <UILanguageFallback>fr-FR</UILanguageFallback>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>JAB5ZZ4AQABkAG0AIQAyEEDAAMAA0AFAAYQGzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Name>admin</Name>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <DisplayName>admin</DisplayName>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ComputerName>por-test</ComputerName>
            <TimeZone>Central European Time</TimeZone>
            <CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>
            <RegisteredOrganization>synaltic</RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>synaltic</RegisteredOwner>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunAsynchronous>
                <RunAsynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Credentials>
                        <Domain>WIN-O4MFN0G8Y76</Domain>
                        <Password>hello</Password>
                        <Username>Administrateur</Username>
                    </Credentials>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                </RunAsynchronousCommand>
            </RunAsynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/administrateur/desktop/win10_22h2_french_x64/sources/install.wim#Windows 10 Pro" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Credential of domain after this code to pass :

```
enter code here
 <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SetupUILanguage>
            <UILanguage>fr-FR</UILanguage>
        </SetupUILanguage>
        <InputLocale>fr-FR</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>fr-FR</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>fr-FR</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>fr-FR</UserLocale>
    </component>
```